# Why has Morgan disappeared since season 9?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Morgan appeared many times in season 8 but he didn't appear in season 9 at all. I probably missed the scene. Then Why did Morgan disappear without indicating? Where did he go?

Answer (score 6):

At the end of season 8 in episode 16, "Wrath", Morgan decides to stay behind at the junkyard because he has decided he can no longer be around people.

> **Morgan:** You don't want to be alone. People. Everything is about people. Everything in this life that's worth a damn.
>
> **Anne:** What's your name?
>
> **Morgan:** Morgan Jones.
>
> **Anne:** Um... You can call me Anne. Let me get my things. We can go.
>
> **Morgan:** Or you can go. I'm gonna stay. I want to be alone. I, um... I need to be.
>
> **Anne:** I thought you said...
>
> **Morgan:** They are, but I can't. I can't.
>
> <sub>*The Walking Dead*, Season 8 Episode 16, "Wrath"</sub>

In season 4 episode 1, "What's Your Story?", of *Fear the Walking Dead* it is explained a bit more with us seeing people from the community trying to convince Morgan to rejoin them. After a while he just decides to hot leg it out of there on his own.

Out of universe though this is because Morgan's character was moved to *Fear the Walking Dead*. This was a decision made between Scott Gimple and the actor Lennie James.

> He continued: "My first reaction was, 'Oh thank God,' but then he said it was much weirder than that. He talked about his new role of overseeing both shows and then he said, 'How would you like to continue the story of Morgan in Fear the Walking Dead?'"
>
> "At the end of the conversation Scott said that he was sure I had loads of questions and, to be honest, I probably did but I couldn't bring a single one of them to my lips. He asked what I wanted to do and all I was that said I was just going to leave and get back to him."
>
> [...]
>
> "We just started talking about it over the next couple of weeks and months as there was a lot to take on board. It wasn't a case of, 'This is going to happen,' it was genuinely a case of what I thought about it, there was absolutely a choice," he added.
>
> "It also wasn't a case of it being if it wasn't me or it wasn't Morgan then it would be somebody else, they were very much saying, 'We were thinking about doing this thing and if you're really not up for it, then we'll go [in] a completely different direction.'"
>
> <sub>[Digital Spy, Exclusive: Lennie James says it was his decision to exit The Walking Dead for spin-off Fear the Walking Dead](https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/a853995/lennie-james-walking-dead-exit-his-decision-fear-the-walking-dead-arrival/)</sub>